# Install DXA on Existing SDL Web 8.1.1 Content Manager

Tags: web8, dxa

1. We have a requirement , one of the client had setup DXA and have 6 publications which includes default DXA publication.

   2. We have our current website running on SDL web 8.1.1 and we have 40 publications and have 15 websites.
   3. What is the right way to merge this.
   4. We want to install DXA on top of the existing Tridion content manager which will create the default publication along with the existing publications.
   5. We configure the storage config in such a way that it will publish all items to broker if its DXA related publication and all other publications to different storageID.

Please let us know if anyone have done this before. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Can you update your question with these details. Do you want to migrate your existing non-dxa sites to DXA based sites? What do you mean by merge? Do you want to access your old publications items from DXA publications or from DXA publications items from old publications?

Comment: We want to install dxa on existing content manger where we already have old publications running on different templates .

Comment: Thanks again we have a CMS instance with 10 publications uses dxa 1.5 running on SDL web 8.1.1 can we use content porter 8 to export and import the 10 publications to another CMS which already contains 40 publications which uses breamvewer , razor and xslt templates running on web8.1.1. This should be possible right .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an example of Rick's powershell, it works with existing publication injection:

```
& .\cms-import.ps1 -cmsUrl "http://domain:80/" -importType "master-only" -masterPublication "existing publication name"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use DXA to create separate websites which don't have any relations with your old publications content you can install it simply by using cms-import.ps1 powershell scripts as mentioned by Rick. You can go through details about importing DXA publication at content manager available at url [Importing the DXA Publications into Content Manager](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v6&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA).

If you want to reuse you old publications content then either you can import DXA publications in existing old publications or change blueprint to inherit any publications. In that case you may required to check for any conflicting items.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh, No we are not going to share any content of old publications with the DXA . So in that case I can import the dxa publications to the existing content manager and make sure I update the storage config to make sure that dxa website publications publish all items to broker and old publications running on different templates to point to respective storage type . In that case we can make sure both dxa and other websites work on same instance.

Comment: Thanks Anand for clarification on your use case. In your case, you can simply follow steps mentioned in first paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The DXA `cms-import.ps1` PowerShell scripts support importing into an existing BluePrint. See the `importType`, `rootPublication` and `masterPublication` parameters.